# Проблема с типами данных

Tags: java, netbeans

Смысл такой: записываю пути файлов в массив, есть переменная которая считает шаг, нужно чтобы картинка jLabel менялась при каждом шаге. подскажите как решить?
вылетает такая ошибка "no suitable constructor found for ImageIcon(java.io.File)"

```
File folder = new File("src\\main\\java\\icon");  //сохранение файлов 
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();          //в массив

hod=hod+1;  

jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(listOfFiles[hod]));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon(java.lang.String)) есть конструктор у класса `javax.swing.ImageIcon` принимающий строку с путём до файла, но нет конструктора, принимающего объект файла.

Таким образом, вам надо как-то так делать:

```
String filePath = listOfFiles[hod].getAbsolutePath();
jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(filePath));
```

Comment: спасибо))) разобрался)))